# Excel: How to find and extract a certain text followed by a series of number in an excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a report I have a cell that contains logs. In that series of logs I want to extract the part where it says "Transaction ID:111-2222".

I tried using the following function but it does not work systematically as the number I'm looking for is not always in the same position within the cell.

[image]

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2;"*Transaction ID:*");MID(A2;127;7);"no")
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you don't have a testable condition to drive the if(), try IF(COUNTIF(A2;"Transaction ID:")>=1;MID(A2;127;7);"no")

Comment: All this data is in a single cell? Would it always have this exact pattern with the "Transaction ID" in-between paranthesis? Does it always have just a single or zero "Transaction ID"s in a single cell? Sidenote: Please update your post to include markdown sample data so users can easily copy-paste the data and help you with a solution.

Comment: You need to share few more logs as well

Comment: check Function [SEARCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) to get start position of string `Transaction` and use it in your MID function

Comment: @SolarMike. A small note but the current `IF()` would work just fine. `COUNTIF()` will either be 0 (equal to false) or a number other than zero (equal to true). No need for the `>=1`. That being said, `COUNTIF()` is definitely not the answer here.

Comment: @JvdV I tend to find that countif does not give zero, but an error which is not taken as false. So I usually use iferror() as well. But it perhaps depends on what I am testing for.

Comment: @SolarMike, I must admit I never had that problem with `COUNTIF()`. The problem is more apparent if one uses `FIND()` or `SEARCH()`.

Comment: Are you aware of this limit: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/maximum-number-of-characters-in-a-cell/m-p/66355

Comment: Thanks all, @Foxfire And Burns And Burns @JvdV! the search function was indeed what I needed. =IFERROR(MID(A2;SEARCH("Transaction ID:";A2)+16;7);"No transaction ID") worked perfectly